# Domain setup on a new RHEL web server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm setting up a web site on a new install of RHEL 5.7, and running into a problem getting the website domain to resolve correctly.

The changes I've made to httpd.conf are to uncomment the NameVirtualHost so it's

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

And uncommented the only VirtualHost entry and changed to read:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myemail@co.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ErrorLog logs/mydomain.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/mydomain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

That's it.

I'm able to ping the server by the domain, but any http requests cause a server timeout error.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is Apache running and listening? (`lsof -i -P | grep 80`) Is there any firewall in front of the device?

Comment: It is.  I'm able to access it via the IP with no problem.  There is a firewall in front, but I am operating from inside the firewall.

Comment: So an HTTP request to the IP works?  Can you verify that the name resolves to the same IP address that you're sending requests to?

Comment: Yeah, when I ping the domain I see that the response is coming from the right IP.

Comment: Ok, so a request to the IP (`http://X.X.X.X/`) works, but a request to the name, which resolves to that IP, times out?  Is the wrong DNS data cached in your OS or browser?  If you `telnet example.com 80`, does it connect?

Comment: Go look in /var/log/httpd/error.log to see if there is any configuration error and while you are at it look at the access.log too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after a long bit of troubleshooting, it seems that the issue was an internal proxy (PAC) file that was blocking access to the domain - nothing to do with the Apache config at all.

Thanks for the help anyway.